# 'tsc' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: typescript

C:\Users\Raya Bhattacharjee\Desktop\Variables>npm install tsc --save
npm WARN deprecated tsc@1.20150623.0: You probably meant to instally 'typescript'. Run 'npm install typescript -g'
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Raya Bhattacharjee\Desktop\Variables\package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Raya Bhattacharjee\Desktop\Variables\package.json'
npm WARN Variables No description
npm WARN Variables No repository field.
npm WARN Variables No README data
npm WARN Variables No license field.

- tsc@1.20150623.0
  added 1 package in 1.269s

C:\Users\Raya Bhattacharjee\Desktop\Variables>tsc variables.ts
'tsc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 0):

Iam also faced this issue solved below mentioned steps.
There is an issue occured during installation process kindly follow below steps.

Uninstall typescript&nodejs completely

Install nodejs from you admin account.It is also occured some problem related path confussion.

I assume you are using windows so go this link

https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/

Download .msi extension file with your is version 32 or 64 bit.

Now install nodejs.

Then open your nodejs cmd or system32 cmd

```
npm install -g typescript
```

Install typescript using above mentioned line.

Once installed open your nodejs cmd check nodejs and typescript installed or not

```
node -v

tsc -v
```

I hope you may have some idea for solve this issue.